# GridView is not scrolling

Tags: android, gridview, scroll

## I've a problem with scrolling the GridView

My requirement is auto retrieving the data from server to GridView

Every thing is ok,but this GridView is not Scrolling down

this is my Java Program,After this xml code will come

This is my Adapter

```
gridAllPackages.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {//blank}
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,int visibleItemCount, int
totalItemCount) {
if (loadingMore) {
if (totalItemCount > mPreviousTotal) {
mPreviousTotal = totalItemCount;
pageNo++;
if (pageNo > 3) {
loadingMore = false;
}
int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;
if((lastInScreen == totalItemCount)&&(loadingMore)&& lastInScreen != 0){
if (pDialog != null && pDialog.isShowing())
pDialog.dismiss();
}}}
}});}
```

End of Adapter

this is my Grid-view

```
private GridView gridAllPackages;
gridAllPackages.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View view, int pos, long arg3) {
try {
TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_gradename);
select_catagory_list.setText(tv.getTag().toString());
lvTag = arg0.getTag().toString();
String tags[] = tv.getTag().toString().split("<<>>");
position_catagory = pos;
if (lvTag.equalsIgnoreCase("Select catagory")) {
if (select_catagory_list.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Select catagory"))
select_catagory_list.setTag("null");
else select_catagory_list.setTag(tags[0]);
listviewPopupWindowProvider.selectedItem(tags[1]);
}
listviewPopupWindowProvider.dismissPopup();
select_catagory_list.setText(tv.getText().toString());
} catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Here is my XML code

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>
<GridView
android:id="@+id/all_relavant_package_grid"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="1151dp"
android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
android:numColumns="3"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:smoothScrollbar="true" >
</GridView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Could be a problem with you adapter. Where is your grid view adapter?

Comment: Try removing this `android:scrollbars="vertical"` gridview has only vertical scroll

Comment: change android:layout_height="1151dp" to android:layout_height="match_parent"

Comment: Thanq for atempting,1 min,I'm going to Add by now,

Comment: Thanq for atempting,now I Added the Adapter,plz check any mistakes in that,THANQ

Comment: Thanq,@ Dharmik,Ur given idea worked

Answer (score 1):

I had similar issue. Turns out the very grid control that was not scrolling was also listening for touch events. verify that that you dont have a similar scenario.

Comment: How to make it scroll able in 'on Touch()' method ?

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem.
The issue is in the fixed height of `gridview`
Replace line-

```
android:layout_height="1151dp"
```

by

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Hope this will help in future who find this problem.

Comment: In my case the issue came from GridView's parent, a ViewPager that had a fixed height. See https://github.com/roomorama/Caldroid/issues/371#issuecomment-189179427 for a more detailed explanation